# How to handle async operations inside a while loop with Node.js?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, asynchronous

For a Node API I must generate a random alphanumeric key, this should be unique and SHORT (I can't use neither uuid or Mongo ObjectID).

I thought this logic:

1. Generate key,
2. Query MongoDB for key existance
3. If key exists, repeat the process,
4. If key doesn't exist, assign it and respond to client.

I tried then:

```
do {
  key = randomKey(8);
  newGroup.key = key;
  Group.findOne({numberId: key}).then(function (foundGroup) {
    console.log("cb");

    if (! foundGroup) {
      console.log("not found")
      notUnique = false;
    }

  }).catch(function (err) {
    return response.send(500);
  });

} while (notUnique);
```

But only I got is an infinite loop, `notUnique` is *never* switching to `true`. Just in case, this was tested against an empy database.

How could I achieve it?

Comment: Can you generate a lot of keys to test? If so, you can query them in bulk with the $in operator. You'll probably find less objects than the keys you generated and then you simply gotta check whether a key exists for which the corresponding object does not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this easily with async module:

```
var async = require('async')

async.forever(
    function(next) {
        key = randomKey(8);

        Group.findOne({numberId: key}).then(function (foundGroup) {
          console.log("cb");

          if (! foundGroup) {
            console.log("not found")
            notUnique = false;
            next(new Error(), key) // break forever loop with empty error message and the key
          }
          else 
            return next() //continue loop

        }).catch(function (err) {
          next(err); //break loop
          return response.send(500);
        });
    },
    function(err, key) {
        if(key){
           newGroup.key = key;
        }

    }
);
```

Comment: This is probably the most practical approach. FYI, there's a proposal for a future version of Javascript (ECMAScript 7) called async/await that would allow you to write this more concisely, and you can use it today thanks to Babel: https://babeljs.io/docs/advanced/transformers/other/async-to-generator/

Answer (score 1):

Since you're already using promises, I'd do something like this: Create a function that recursively returns a promise, creating a promise chain, and eventually throws an error when a condition is/isn't met. You then just need to catch that final error.

**edit**: updated to return the key

```
function find(){
    var key = randomKey(8);
    return Group.findOne({numberId: key })
    .then(function(foundGroup) {
        if(foundGroup) return find(); // recursion
        else throw key;
    }).catch(function(err){ // in case Group.findOne throws
        throw key; 
    });
}
find().catch(function(key){
    return response.send(key);
});
```

The `find` function here will keep calling itself recursively as long as it keeps finding a valid object. And since it returns a promise they will all be chained automatically.

If and eventually when it doesn't find the object, or `Group.findOne` throws an error, the key is thrown.

`find().catch` will catch that eventual error, which will be the key.